# How do you download files over HTTP with Vala?

Tags: vala, libsoup

I attempted to use libsoup-2.4 with https://valadoc.org/libsoup-2.4/Soup.RequestFile.html

but the creation of RequestFile is protected and I can't see any operation that returns that object or an object that inherits RequestFile.

The following works, but I was wondering if there was a shorter or better way, whether it is with the same library or others.

```java
// Where url is a string containing the file location (https://...)
Soup.Request request = session.request (url);
InputStream stream = request.send ();

// Create the file
File file = File.new_for_path ("Example File.zip");
FileOutputStream os = file.create (FileCreateFlags.REPLACE_DESTINATION);

// Write bytes to the file
os.splice (stream, OutputStreamSpliceFlags.CLOSE_TARGET);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this can be done more easily with gio-2.0. Just open first file by URL, the second file locally, and copy the first one to the second. The following example downloads the code of this html page.

```
void main () {
    var file_from_http = File.new_for_uri ("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61021171/how-do-you-download-files-over-http-with-vala");
    File local_file = File.new_for_path("./stackoverflow.html");
    file_from_http.copy(local_file, FileCopyFlags.OVERWRITE);
}
```

Comment: Does this work on Windows as well? I think GIO uses GVfs for its HTTP back end and I'm not sure how well that works on other platforms

Comment: GIO is cross-platform. This is also confirmed by the fact that we have gio-unix and gio-windows I think.

https://imgur.com/gallery/54i6ew1

Comment: Yes, GIO is a high level, cross-platform, API. It works well with files and sockets, but other protocols require different back ends. GIO uses [GVfs](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/gvfs) for a [number of schemes](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/gvfs/schemes) and they each use their own [back ends](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/gvfs/backends). It's good to know that the HTTP back end (using GVfs and libsoup) works in a pure Windows environment, thanks